# Mixing time of a biased random walk on a line segment

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, random-walk, mixing

The mixing time $t_{mix}$ of a $\beta$ biased random walk on a line segment $\{0,1,\cdots n\}$ is given by $\beta^{-1}n+O(\sqrt{n})$. I am not interested in the proof but an understanding of the statement I was told: "If we know that the average time it takes to reach $n$ from $0$ is $\beta^{-1}n$ (inverse of speed times distance) and if we know that the chain mixes when the walk reaches $n$, then $O(\sqrt{n})$ term follows from the central limit theorem (CLT)". May I know how this follows from the CLT?

I know by CLT, if $X_i$'s are iid with finite variance and $S_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ , then $S_n = ES_n + O(\sqrt{n})$ but am not sure how that is analogous to $t_{mix} = \beta^{-1}n + O(\sqrt{n})$? Is $t_{mix}$ a sum of $n$ iid random variables?

Comment: By the CLT, the chain is at $\beta k + O(\sqrt{k})$ at time $k$ for $k$ large. The chain mixes when $n = \beta k + O(\sqrt{k})$; since $k$ and $n$ are of the same order you can rewrite this as $\beta k = n + O(\sqrt{n})$ or $k = \beta^{-1}n + O(\sqrt{n})$. I think this is the intuition.

Comment: I see, thanks, one question, how can I convince myself that $k$ and $n$ are of the same order?

Comment: It's in the statement $n = \beta k + O(\sqrt{k})$. When $k$ is large, you won't notice $O(\sqrt{k})$, so $n \approx \beta k$ or $k \approx \beta^{-1}n$. If variables are linearly related, they are of the same order (saying that something is $O(n)$ is saying that it is smaller than $c \dot n$ for some constant $c$).

Comment: Got it now, thanks.